# Prestashop 1.7 DisplayPaymentByBinaries hook for paymentmodule

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am creating a paymentmodule for Prestashop 1.7 and i'm trying to use the hook DisplayPaymentByBinaries because i can't use the submit button.

underneath you will find my code:

```
    public function hookDisplayPaymentByBinaries()
{
    if (!Currency::exists('EUR', 0))
    {
        return  '<p class="payment_module" style="color:red;">' .
        $this->l('Payment Methods are only available when Euros are activated.') .
        '</p>';
    }
    $issuer_setting = $this->getConfigValue('MY_ISSUERS');

    try {

        $methods = $this->api->methods->all();
        $issuer_list = in_array($issuer_setting, array(self::ISSUERS_ALWAYS_VISIBLE, self::ISSUERS_ON_CLICK)) ? $this->_getIssuerList() : array();
    } catch (MY_API_Exception $e) {
        $methods = array();
        $issuer_list = array();

        if ($this->getConfigValue('MY_DEBUG_LOG') == self::DEBUG_LOG_ERRORS)
        {
            Logger::addLog(__METHOD__ . ' said: ' . $e->getMessage(), My::ERROR);
        }
        if ($this->getConfigValue('MY_DISPLAY_ERRORS'))
        {
            return
                '<p class="payment_module" style="color:red;">' .
                $e->getMessage() .
                '</p>'
                ;
        }
    }
    $this->setBinary = true;
    $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'methods'        => $methods,
            'issuers'        => $issuer_list,
            'issuer_setting' => $issuer_setting,
            'images'         => $this->getConfigValue('MY_IMAGES'),
            'warning'        => $this->warning,
            'msg_pay_with'   => $this->lang['Pay with %s'],
            'msg_bankselect' => $this->lang['Select your bank:'],
            'module'         => $this,
        ));

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'my_methods.tpl');
}
```

### As described by prestashop:

As you may read it above, you must not have a submit button into your module’s HTML code, because PrestaShop will automatically generate it. If you can’t remove the submit button from the form for some reasons (e.g.: the form is generated by binaries), we have implemented another way to make your module PrestaShp 1.7 compatible. But, note that this is NOT the recommended way to do it.

To do this, you’ll need to implement a supplementary hook: displayPaymentByBinaries. It’s made to display the payment form, and it will replace the unique payment button in the checkout.

### You’ll also need to set the $binary variable to true. It will adapt the behavior to hide the payment button and replace it by the form when the payment option is selected.

I have implemented my code and my payment options are showing, but the submit button is still there. As you can see in my function, i used:

```
$this->setBinary = true;
```

in the header of the file i have added:

```
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption;
```

The setBinary function which im calling (from the paymentoption file):

```
public function setBinary($binary)
{
    $this->binary = $binary;
    return $this;
}
```

Can someone please help me out on what i'm doing wrong here? In other words, what do i have to alter to remove the submit button?

Thank you all beforehand.

---

Underneath is my working awnser thanks to [@UnLoCo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179545/unloco).

```
    public function hookPaymentOptions($params)
{
    if (!Currency::exists('EUR', 0))
    {
        return;
    }

    try {
        $methods = $this->api->methods->all();
    } catch (My_API_Exception $e) {
        $methods = array();

        if ($this->getConfigValue('My_DEBUG_LOG') == self::DEBUG_LOG_ERRORS)
        {
            Logger::addLog(__METHOD__ . ' said: ' . $e->getMessage(), My::ERROR);
        }

        return;
    }


    $payment_options = array();
    foreach($methods as $method)
    {
        $newOption = new PaymentOption();
        $newOption->setBinary(true);

        $payment_options[] = $newOption;
    }

    return $payment_options;
}
```

Comment: I understood that you need to set the binary field to true in the returned payment option, you need to include your `hookPaymentOptions` code

Comment: @UnLoCo Thank you for being the first one in ages to even respond to one of my questions and thank you for pointing this out to me. I overlooked this in the manual. Let me give this a go...

Comment: @UnLoCo I have it working thanks to you! I managed to figure out how to alter the code so i didn't have to use `hookDisplayPaymentByBinaries`. I have updated my question to show people how to implement binary in `hookPaymentOptions`. I wanted to ask you to post your comment as an awnser and the working code from my question into it as well. And I will mark your awnser as right. Thank you again for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: Glad I could help, I added some "pseudo" code as an answer, cheers

Comment: @UnLoCo well dear Sir, as promised I have marked it as correct. And thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the binary to true in the returned payment option(s)

```
public function hookPaymentOptions($params)
{
    //...

    $payment_option = new PaymentOption();
    $payment_option->setBinary(true);

    return array(
        $payment_option
    );    
}
```